# Trying to extend Laravel 10's loggin with custom functions

Tags: php, laravel, monolog, laravel-10

I want to be able to do the following statement

```php
Log::channel('database')->category('asdasd')->info('This will be logged to the database.');
```

and I have it so that it inserts the message to the logs table if I take out the `->category()` part of it.

I have a `category` column in my `logs` table and I want to insert the passed in string as the row's value for that column. I keep getting `Call to undefined method Monolog\Logger::category()` error. I am not sure what to do at this point. I'd really appreciate some help. ty

```php
<?php

namespace App\Logger;

use Monolog\Logger;
use App\Logger\DatabaseLogHandler;
use Monolog\Processor\GitProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\ProcessIdProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\MemoryUsageProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\MemoryPeakUsageProcessor;

class DatabaseLogger extends Logger
{

    protected $category;

    public function category(string $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Create a custom Monolog instance.
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config): Logger
    {
        $logger = new self('database');
        $logger->pushHandler(new DatabaseLogHandler());
        $logger->pushProcessor(new WebProcessor());
        $logger->pushProcessor(new GitProcessor());
        $logger->pushProcessor(new ProcessIdProcessor());
        $logger->pushProcessor(new MemoryUsageProcessor());
        $logger->pushProcessor(new MemoryPeakUsageProcessor());
        return $logger;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Logger;

use Monolog\Level;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;
use Monolog\LogRecord;
use App\Models\Log;

class DatabaseLogHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    public function __construct(int|string|Level $level = Level::Debug, bool $bubble = true)
    {
        parent::__construct($level, $bubble);
    }

    protected function write($record): void
    {
        $record = is_array($record) ? $record : $record->toArray();
        Log::create([
            'level' => $record['level_name'],
            'message' => $record['message'],
            'context' => $record['context'] ? json_encode($record['context']) : null,
            'extra' => $record['extra'] ? json_encode($record['extra']) : null,
        ]);
    }

}
```

````php
  'database' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via' => App\Logger\DatabaseLogger::class,
        ],
    ```
````